# Adding digits within an arraylist with a guideline

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm a newbie coder and in need some help. Im trying to add the digits of a number together according to a number corresponding to how many digits I can use. Im using Eclipse Juno and using a separate text file for using my numbers. Though it isn't much This is what I have now:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

String token1 = "";
Scanner infile1 = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
ArrayList<String> temps = new ArrayList<String>();
//Adding Input files to the Arraylist
while(infile1.hasNext()){
    token1 = infile1.next();
      temps.add(token1);    
}
infile1.close();
//Calling the Numbers from ArrrayList temps
    for(int x = 0; x < temps.size(); x++) {
 System.out.println(x + " " + temps.get(x));
 for(x = 0; x < temps.size(); x++ ){

 }
}


    } 

}
```

The numbers are
9678415 7, 
9678415 6, 
9678415 5, 
9678415 4, 
2678515 3, 
Number to add, digits to use. The input.txt file does not have commas

Comment: I forgot to mention to return the highest number value

Comment: The description of what you want to do is not clear. Please show an example of the input and also of the expected output.

Comment: The Sample output should be 986541, 987641, 98765, 9876, and 875

Comment: Now I am even more confused. Please [edit] the question to clearly show input values, the method of calculation and the expect output values.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly how you do this is going to depend on what the data looks like in the file.  You say it's not delimited by commas so I will have to assume they are separated by lines.  You will need to separate the values within the strings and convert to int; so the below should do what you are attempting, if I understand the question. (full disclosure, it's been a little while since I've written in Java and I don't have a way to test this right now, make sure I haven't made any basic syntax errors)

```
ArrayList<Integer> totalArray = ArrayList<Integer>();
for(String tStr : temps){
    int tempTotal = 0;
    String[] numArray = tStr.split(" ");
    for(int x = 0; x < Integer.parseInt(numArray[1]){
        int y = Integer.parseInt(numArray[0].substring(x,x+1));
        tempTotal += y;
    } 
    totalArray.add(tempTotal);
}
```

There are probably better ways to get the highest value, but since I have been out of this for a little while, I'm just going to do it in the most basic way I can think of.

```
int highestValue = 0;
for (Integer x : totalArray){
    if(highestValue<=x){
        highestValue = x;
    }
}
return highestValue;
```

Comment: P.S. I think that the enhanced for loop that I am using in this answer is only available in versions 1.5 and later.  We are pretty well past that at this point and I would imagine most systems are using a version later than that, but thought you might need to know.